# How to re-intialize Google Maps with Marker when click button

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have embed a map with Google Maps api and it work fine.
But, I want to make "Pin My Location" button (clicked by user), and when user click that button, my map reloaded with new marker (marker pointed to user latitude and longitude). I have been successfully get the user latitude and longitude when user click the button, and now, how to make my map loaded with user new latitude and longitude?
Below is my code:

```
<script>
function getClicked(latLng) {
console.log(latLng);
}
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: start[0],
        lng: start[1]
      },
      zoom: zoom,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    <?php if (isset($start)) { ?>
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: {
          lat: start[0],
          lng: start[1]
        }
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        geocoder.geocode({
          'location': {
            lat: start[0],
            lng: start[1]
          }
        }, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      });
    <?php } ?>


    // search box
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // zoom ke search box
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    //popup window
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // map diklik
    map.addListener('click', function(e) {

      if (marker != undefined) marker.setMap(null);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: e.latLng
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        geocoder.geocode({
          'location': e.latLng
        }, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      });

      getClicked([e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng()])
    });

    // alamat di search
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      if (marker != undefined) marker.setMap(null);

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }

        // Create a marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          geocoder.geocode({
            'location': place.geometry.location
          }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              if (results[0]) {
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
        });

        var latlng = {
          lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
        }
        getClicked([place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()])

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });

      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }

  function getClicked(latlng) {
    console.log(latlng)
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>

<script>
let pinMyLocation = document.querySelector('.pin-btn');
pinMyLocation.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
//I have new user latitude and longitude here
//I want to reload map here
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the center of the map to the clicked location?  Where are the coordinates of that location?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including any CSS/HTML required (preferably a Stack Snippet that demonstrates your issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to modify the map's initial location you need some form of permanent storage - `localStorage` and `cookies` seem the most obvious with `localStorage` offering a better option imo.

The below code uses `geolocation` to try to identify the user's location and the `Pin It` button would use that location to relocate the map and marker. Alternatively by simply clicking on the map at any location will also relocate map and marker.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Locate & Pin</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                /* default location and basic options... */
                const latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 51.512547, -0.134022 );
                const options = {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center:latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                
                /* Pinned location - stored in localStorage */
                const STORE='gmap-location';
                /*
                    if the store does not exist, 
                    create it with basic options.
                */
                if( localStorage.getItem( STORE )==null ){
                    localStorage.setItem( STORE, JSON.stringify( { lat:latlng.lat(), lng:latlng.lng(), zoom:options.zoom, type:options.mapTypeId } ) );
                }
                /* fetch details from local storage container */
                let json=JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( STORE ) );
                /* update map configuration options with saved values */
                options.center=new google.maps.LatLng( json.lat,json.lng );
                options.zoom=json.zoom;
                options.mapTypeId=json.type;
                
                
                
                /* create the map... */
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                
                
                
                
                const addMarker=function( latlng ){
                    /*
                        add a basic marker ( using only latlng )
                        - additional settings can be assigned 
                        as second argument - Object.
                    */
                    let a=arguments;
                    let args={
                        position:latlng,
                        map:map
                    };
                    if( typeof( a[1] )=='object' && Object.keys( a[1] ).length > 0 ){
                        args=Object.assign( args, a[1] );
                    }

                    let marker=new google.maps.Marker( args );
                    return marker;
                };
                
                
                
                
                const mapclickhandler=function(e){
                    /*
                        The user clicks on the map
                        and that location is used 
                        as the "pinned" location -
                        location & zoom are stored
                        in local storage.
                    */
                    addMarker( e.latLng );
                    map.setCenter( e.latLng );
                    localStorage.setItem( STORE, JSON.stringify( { lat:e.latLng.lat(), lng:e.latLng.lng(), zoom:map.getZoom(), type:map.getMapTypeId() } ) );
                    location.reload();
                };
                
                
                
                
                const bttnclickhandler=function( event ){
                    if( this.name=='reset' ){
                        localStorage.removeItem( STORE );
                        location.reload();
                    }else{
                        /*
                            Pin-It
                            ------
                            The user's location is found using `navigator.geolocation`
                            a marker is added at that location and the location & zoom
                            are stored in local storage
                        */
                        const evtSuccess=function(pos){
                            const latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude );
                            addMarker( latlng );
                            map.setCenter( latlng );
                            localStorage.setItem( STORE, JSON.stringify( { lat:pos.coords.latitude, lng:pos.coords.longitude, zoom:map.getZoom() } ) );
                        };
                        
                        const evtFailure=function( err ){
                            console.warn( err )
                        };
                        const args={ enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout:10000 };
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( evtSuccess, evtFailure, args );               
                    }
                }
                
                
                
                
                /* respond to button clicks */
                let bttns=document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]');
                    bttns.forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener( 'click', bttnclickhandler ) );
                
                
                /* respond to map clicks */
                google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click', mapclickhandler );
                
                
                /* add marker for default location */
                addMarker( map.getCenter() );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <input type='button' name='pin' value='Pin It' />
        <input type='button' name='reset' value='Reset' />
    </body>
</html>
```